# How to create a simple protected route in SvelteKit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to **create a simple protected route** for my sveltekit project. But, *the states are not changing*. I want to know what I am doing wrong in the following code?

Here is my code for index.svelte page:

```
<script>
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
    import { user } from '../stores/store.js';
    const logInUser = () => {
        user.set(2);
        goto('/about');
    };
</script>

<button on:click={logInUser}>Log in</button>
<br />
<p>
    Direct Access to About Page.
    <a href="/about">About</a>
</p>
<slot />
```

Here is my code for stores/store.js file:

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const user = writable();
```

Here is my code for about.svelte page that I want to protect from non-logged in user:

```
<script>
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
    import { user } from '../stores/store.js';
    const logOutUser = () => {
        user.set(1);
        goto('/');
        console.log(user);
    };
    console.log(user);
</script>

{#if user > 1}
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <br />
    <button on:click={logOutUser}>Log out</button>
{:else}
    <p>Protected Route <a href="/">home</a></p>
{/if}

<slot />
```

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: To get the _value_ of a store use the `$` notation: `{#if $user > 1}`